# ASP.NET Core : handle exception if database is not connected or does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this little project that I'm working on ASP.NET Core and I have managed to complete the CRUD operations part on it. Now what I have to do is handle errors and one of them is handling whether the database is connected/exists or not.

PS: my connection string works all fine and I can use all the crud operations with it. I just want to give the user a message whenever the database gets deleted or something.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(DbContext context)
{
    DbConnection conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        ViewBag.Message = "Success connecting!";
        return View("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Error connecting!";
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Also I think I have to mention that my connection string is set in `appsettings.json` file.

I am new to ASP.NET Core and this is where I'm stuck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the database does get deleted,  what is your user supposed to do about it? And what exactly are you ‘stuck’ on?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or some other data access method?

Comment: I just want to show i'm a "better" message, other than directing him to a c# error page with bunch of codes that the user might not understand.


Yes, I am using EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core applications are configured using dependency injection. EF Core can be added to this configuration using AddDbContext in the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs.  For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
}
```

The ApplicationDbContext class must expose a public constructor with a DbContextOptions parameter. This is how context configuration from AddDbContext is passed to the DbContext. For example:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext

{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext can then be used in ASP.NET Core controllers or other services through constructor injection. For example:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

When performing CRUD operations through DBcontext, if the CURD operations executed successfully, it means the Database is Connected successfully, otherwise it means there is something wrong when access/update the database, then you can use Try-Catch statement to capture the exception and return  the special message.

reference to:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

If you want to give the user a message whenever the database gets deleted or something. Look the demo :

Success :

[image]

Suppose a scenario where the database connection fails:

1.Add code in Index action:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {         
            try
            {
                _context.Database.GetDbConnection().Close();
                _context.Database.GetDbConnection().Dispose();
                var result = await _context.Movie.ToListAsync();
                ViewBag.Message = "Success connecting!";
                return View(result);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error connecting!";
                return View("Index");

            }

        }
```

2.Add `@ViewBag.Message` and `@if (Model?.Count() > 0)`  to your index view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
@ViewBag.Message
...
@if (Model?.Count() > 0)
{
foreach (var item in Model) {

//contain your model item...
}
}
```

fail:

[image]

Comment: can i contact you on email? @Qing Guo

Comment: I'm very sorry, I can't give you a private email, I can only communicate in the forum. If you have any questions about this post, you can continue to ask, and I will still help to solve them. If you have new questions, you can also open a new post, someone will help you.@arddd